# Example of meromorphic function with given proerty

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to construct meromorphic function which has pole at each natural number with residue as same natural number.

I attempted as following $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}n/(z-n)$.
But problem is that this series is not convergent .Please can some one give suggestion to make above example work by doing some maniputation.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe use terms $a_n/(z-n)^2$ with an appropriate choice of $a_n$ to give the desired residues?

Comment: @MPW The residue of this function at $n$ is $0$ whatever $a_n$ is.

Comment: So it is. Then I would try the approach suggested in the answer(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed $z \in \Bbb C$ and $n \to \infty$ we have (using the geometric
series)
$$
 \frac{n}{z-n} = -1 - \frac{z}{n}  + O\left(\frac zn \right)^2 
$$
which suggests to consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{n}{z-n} + 1 + \frac zn \right)
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^2}{n(z-n)}
$$

Comment: Ah yes this is a better answer

Answer (score 2):

If you can put poles in other places too: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{z-n} + \frac{n}{z+n} - \frac{in}{z-in} - \frac{in}{z+in} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2}{z^4-n^4} $$ which is convergent as it's 'no worse than' $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$. But the other answer shows you don't need to.